# C++: Similar mod operations printing different values

Tags: c++, modulo

I am trying to perform some custom operation but I noticed the following error.
While calculating the value of `t`, I get desired output but for `s` I am getting negative values for no reason.

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    char s = 'r';
    char temp1 = s;

    char t = 'a';
    char temp2 = t;

    s = (int(temp1) % int(96)) + (int(s) % int(96)) + 96;
    cout << int(s) << " ";

    t = (int(temp2) % int(96)) + (int(t) % int(96)) + 96;
    cout << int(t) << endl;
}
```

> I have to use this logic elsewhere in a bigger program, I am getting the same error in both the cases
>
> **Output**
>   -124
>   98
>
> > *I don't understand why -124 is begin printed*

Comment: code style: don't say `int(96)`.  Just say `96`

Comment: *I don't understand why -124 is begin printed*  -- What did you expect it to print?  Whatever your answer is, then consider what `char` means, since that is the variable you want to store the result in.

Comment: Did you perhaps want to use `unsigned char`?

Comment: @selbie I am still getting the same error

Comment: Of course you get the same error if you later cast the unsigned char to int which are signed

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie it should print 132

Comment: @SudhanvaNarayana -- ok, so what is the range of a `signed char`?

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie -128 to 127?

Comment: @SudhanvaNarayana  So there is your answer.  See how simple that was?  132 is not in the range of -128 to 127.  Its bit pattern actually yields -124 if we're talking 2's complement.

Comment: @SudhanvaNarayana Just to fill you in -- here is the bit pattern for 132 -- `10000100`.  Two's complement says to reverse the bits and add 1,  So if you do that `01111011 + 1` = `01111100` == `124`.  But since the most significant bit (the sign bit) of the original number was `1`, then the number becomes `-124`.  You can also think of it as a circle.  The highest number is 127, to go higher than that you get into the negative range, starting from `-128` and going down.  So `132` is `127 + 5` = `-128, -127, -126, -125, -124`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are hitting an overflow issue with an 8-bit integer type (char).

This expression is

```
s = (int(temp1) % int(96)) + (int(s) % int(96)) + 96;
```

Algebraically, your code simplifies to this:

```
s = 114 % 96 + 114 % 96 + 96;

s = 18 + 18 + 96;

s = (signed char)132;  // overflow!  132 won't fit in range [-128..127]

s = -124;
```

Change the declaration of s and t to be of type int.  And some helpful ways to improve your code style are made as well:

```
int main()
{
    int s = 'r';
    int temp1 = s;

    int t = 'a';
    int temp2 = t;

    s = temp1 % 96 + s % 96 + 96;
    cout << s << " ";

    t = temp2 % 96 + t % 96 + 96;
    cout << t << endl;
}
```

Comment: What if that char is a string? (Imagine I am looping through the string s[i])

Comment: You can cast the value back to `char` before printing it out.  E.g. `cout << (char)t << endl`.  But I have no idea what printing out "132" as a char value will render on the screen.

Comment: It is out of range assignment, not overflow. (Overflow means when the result of arithmetic operation is out of range of the type of the result type as deduced from the operands; but assignment is not an arithmetic operation). For signed integer types, overflow is usually undefined, whereas out-of-range assignment is implementation-defined.